# Magento 1.9.2. - Display attribute value in his current language

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, backend

My code is this:

```
$simple_product->getAttributeText('attribute')
```

I would display attribute text value in his different language in my view.phtml. If i use getAttributeText('attribute') it shows me the value of the admin column of the attribute and not in other languages. I attached a screen for this:

[image]

This operation I want to perform on the associated products of the configurable product and therefore I extracted the value of the attribute as follows:

```
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()- 
>addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){$simple_product- 
 >getAttributeText('color');
}
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $StoreAttrValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->setStoreId({{store_id}})->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Or

You have to set store ID.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$_product->setStoreId($storeId)->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

Comment: Hi i tried this but not work, i update my question because I had not written something

Comment: Try to reindex data.

Comment: The error that brings me back is this: Call to a member function setStoreId() on null. I tried but ever with the same result.

Comment: Try next code & let me know

Comment: I tried man, not report to me anything error but show only admin value and not the translated value